# Wordpress Custom Widget - Javascript output not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an issue with Javascript that I created for my custom widget.

Here is my code from the javascript to how I call it in my widget.

**Custom.js**

```
     var wrapper = $('#wrapper');   
     $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://api.graphcms.com/simple/v1/SampleAPI",
     contentType: "application/json",
     headers: {
     Authorization: "bearer ******"
   },
   data: JSON.stringify({query: "query  { allProducts { id title } }"})
    }).done(function(data) {

    for( var key in data ) {

 for (var i = 0; i<data[key].allProducts.length; i++)
 {
     console.log(data[key].allProducts[i]);
     container = $('<div id="data" class="container"></div>');
     wrapper.appendTo(container);
     container.appendTo('<input type=checkbox name="id" value=' + 
      data[key].allProducts[i].id + '>' + data[key].allProducts[i].title  );             
 }   

}
```

**functions.php**

Here is how I'm calling the Jquery in my functions.php file for the template:

```
   function jquery_import() {

      wp_deregister_script('jquery');
      wp_register_script('jquery',https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', array(), '3.3.1', true);  
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

   }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_import' );
```

Here is how I'm calling my custom javascript file:

```
   function custom_wp_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );

   }    
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

**My Custom Widget**

Finally, in my widget here is the following div statement:

```
   <div id="wrapper"> </div>
```

Based on my javascript, data is coming in, however, the information is not displayed in my widget. Why it isn't showing in my widget?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Answer (score 0):

You have the appendTo backwards... instead of appending to your wrapper, you are appending wrapper to an element that only exists in the javascript, not on the dom.  try append instead of appendTo

Comment: I did make that change, and nothing is still showing.

Comment: Two questions:  is custom.js wrapped in a $(function() { .....  })?  Is custom.js in your <head>, or at the end of <body>?

Comment: No, and the custom.js is in the <head>

Comment: Then you'll likely note that if you console.log(wrapper) immediately after you declare it you'll see it is not actually in the returned jQuery collection as it doesn't exist on the page, yet.  You need to wait for document.load.  jQuery has a great way to do that - simply wrap your code in a $(function() { // your code here });

Answer (score 0):

Well, I added a $(function(){....}), and the output is showing.